# How to disable Django-OTP / Double Authentification / 2FA

Tags: django

I've lost my key for 2FA authentification on a Django website with django-otp. In that case, I had to disable django-otp to get back the QRCode on my new mobile phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have lost your access to your website and can't use 2FA that is activated on your Django with django-otp plugin, **comment that line in your urls.py** :

```
admin.site.__class__ = OTPAdminSite
```

To :

```
# admin.site.__class__ = OTPAdminSite
```

After, try to login without 2FA, get your QRCode and uncomment the line to enable the double-authentification.